# Testing SQLite database with AndroidTestCase

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-sqlite

Hi I am trying to write unit-tests for my android app with SQLite db with AndroidTestCase. The tests will pass, but every time when I run the test, I get this error ((exception is thrown):

```
09-17 13:49:15.917: E/AndroidRuntime(11049): FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
09-17 13:49:15.917: E/AndroidRuntime(11049): java.lang.SecurityException: Calling from not trusted UID!
09-17 13:49:15.917: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
09-17 13:49:15.917: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
09-17 13:49:15.917: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.finishInstrumentation(ActivityManagerNative.java:2954)
09-17 13:49:15.917: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.finishInstrumentation(ActivityThread.java:4466)
09-17 13:49:15.917: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):    at android.app.Instrumentation.finish(Instrumentation.java:196)
09-17 13:49:15.917: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:574)
09-17 13:49:15.917: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

my code is here:

```
package com.gamebook.database.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;
import android.test.IsolatedContext;
import android.test.RenamingDelegatingContext;
import android.test.mock.MockContentResolver;
import android.test.mock.MockContext;



public class DBQueriesTest extends AndroidTestCase {

     private static final String TEST_FILE_PREFIX = "test_";
     private DBQueries dbQueries;

     @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

            MockContentResolver resolver = new MockContentResolver();
            RenamingDelegatingContext targetContextWrapper = new RenamingDelegatingContext(
                    new MockContext(), // The context that most methods are delegated to
                    getContext(), // The context that file methods are delegated to
                    TEST_FILE_PREFIX);
            Context context = new IsolatedContext(resolver, targetContextWrapper);
            setContext(context);


        dbQueries = new DBQueries(context);
        dbQueries.openWritable();
    }


     @Override
     protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
         super.tearDown();

         dbQueries.close();
         dbQueries = null;
     }


    public void testPreConditions() {
       assertNotNull(dbQueries);
    }

  public void testWriteActionsNoAction(){
    State state = new State(5);
    state.setAkce(new HashMap<Integer,Action>());
    long ret = dbQueries.writeActions(state, 10);
    long exp = 1;
    assertEquals(exp, ret);
}


}
```

note: when I am debugging the test, there is no exception thrown (enough time for init app or for what ?).

**UPDATE** When the test run on the real device with 2.3.3 android or on 4.1.1 emulator, test will pass and any exception is thrown, but emulator with 4.3 android throws the exception. I haven't tested it on real device with 4.3 yet.

So my question is what should I fix or how should I test it ? 
Should I use InstrumentationTestCase or something else ? or does know anyone some tutorial for db testing ?

Answer (score 0):

If I assume correctly, you're performing DB tests from another project. Correct?

If yes, you should use ContentProvider to access DB. For that you have to create ContentProvider in your application.

In the other hand if some calls are asynchronous you might need to wait until the asynchronous call has ended, e.g. using Semaphore or CountDownLatch (its up to you).

Comment: yes the testing classes are in another test project. Ok could you explain me why I can't use my approach ?

Comment: and why the exception is thrown ?